# Why adherent points of Natural Numbers are only natural numbers

Tags: calculus

I am studying adherent points and I don't understand why some of the number between two natural numbers can't be adherent to IN. Because supposedly the they are adherent if you can have a neighborhood centered on it which intersects the set. And I would think that is possible?

Comment: To be an adherent point *ALL* neighborhoods must intersect.  Not just one.  *EVERY* point $c$ has at least *one* neighborhood that intersects *EVERY* non-emptyset $M$.  Just let $x \in M$ and take a radius that is larger than $|c-x|$.  Example.  $-1235$ has a neighborhood that intersects $(+647893,+657893.2)$.  The neighborhood with radius $649129$ not only intersect $(+647893,+657893.2)$, it engulfs it.  But clearly $-1235$ is not an adherent point of $(+647893,+657893.2)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$, let $r$ be the distance from $x$ to the closest natural number. Then $(x-r,x+r)\cap\mathbb N=\emptyset$  and $(x-r,x+r)$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to say there is a neighborhood of the point that intersects the set.  You need $\underline {\rm{every}}$ neighborhood of the point to intersect the set.

Answer (score 0):

> Because supposedly the they are adherent if you can have a neighborhood centered on it which intersects the set. And I would think that is possible?

They are adherent if *ALL* neighborhoods intersect; not just one.

And it should be clear that if $x$ is not an integer you can take a very small neighborhood of $x$ that is too small to include either the integer below $x$ or above $x$.

Formally: if $n < x < n+1$ and $0< r< \min(x-n, (n+1)-x)$ then $n < x-r < x < x+r < n+1$ and $(x-r,x+r) \cap \mathbb N = \emptyset$.